# Trying to get string value from activity1 to fragment of activity 2 but it returns as null. GetArgument always returns as null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to get bundle extras from activity 1 to fragment of activity 2 but getargument() always returns as null.

```
     //Using this to get string in fragment
     String value = getArguments().getString("abc");

    //activity1 code that i used to get the extras
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("abc", townextra);
    UserFragment myFrag = new UserFragment();
    myFrag.setArguments(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("params", "Your String data");
// set MyFragment Arguments
MyFragment myObj = new MyFragment();
myObj.setArguments(bundle);
```

The Fragment.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam = getArguments().getString("params");
        }
    }
```

But will be better if you show the code how you pass data between activities and then use my answer.
And please add your fragment code.

Comment: Intent startrequest  = new Intent(StartRequest.this, ChatPageCustomer.class);
        String message = town.getText().toString();

        startrequest.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

I have used this code to get extras from activity 1 to activity 2.
but when i try to send it to fragment of activity 2 it gives null. i have tried you code too but it still stays null. i donot need to change any value in the view i just need it in the background for a firebase query.

Comment: Are you getting the passed string from `activity1` to `activity 2` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with logic of passing data.

Correct way would be: Pass data from Activity1 to Activity2, and then from Activity2 to Fragment.

Comment: i have done it from activity 1 to activity 2 already. extras show fine in activity 2 but when i call them in fragment getargument just comes null.

Comment: In that case, Spritzig's answer will help you

Comment: still null..
anyother approach to do this??

Comment: Only if you share your activities and fragments here.

Comment: @Said you are right only if he add the code we can help, by the way my answer which I answered I am using in most of my projects and it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

all fixed. I added a new function on my activity 2 to create fragment. instead of doing it in oncreat. it all works fine, thanks